# Update app on iPad that has been removed from registered devices on developer.apple.com

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, hockeyapp

I've removed ~40 devices from the iOS device list for developing/testing at the new year. We updated the software on 20 used iPads, and, in the process, our technician successfully updated the app, which surprised me, since I removed those UUIDs 
from developer.apple.com – can anyone explain why this still works?

Notes:
I'm using HockeyApp to distribute the app to devices, the app will prompt users to update if there is a newer version on HockeyApp.

Comment: what was the license which was used to distribute the app, if it is enterprise provision, yes it doesnt need device registration

Comment: it's not an enterprise provision. *edit: grammar

Comment: got you, looks like @chedabob has already answered it. since the .mobileprovision living on the phone doesn't know what happened on the provisioning portal and as long as .mobileprovision is valid, signed apps will work.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you remove them from your developer profile, their UUIDs will still be available in the provisioning profiles that have already been issued. It's only when the certificates associated with those profiles expire, that the devices are truly removed from your profile.

If you were to regenerate those provisioning profiles without those devices, and then resign your app, it would block installation.

Comment: This makes sense to me, thanks for the reply chedabob.